# My function compiled but it is ignoring the statement OracleSQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

I created a function that finds trip id: Given customer, vehicle owner, source, destination, date. Return the trip id (assume a customer will take the same trip only once in a given date). It was ignoring my statement.
Here is my code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION findingID  (findID in number)
return number is
return_id trips.trips_id%type;
begin 
select trips_id, date_of_trip, source_town, destination_town
into return_id
from trips
where trip_id = findID;
return return_id;
END;
```

[Here is the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zg80b.png)

Comment: Please edit the question and show the table definition for trips table, and the code that is calling the function.

Comment: Your subject says that the function compiled but the syntax appears to be invalid.  You're selecting 4 columns but providing only 1 variable in the `into` clause.  That doesn't make sense.  If you remove the other 3 columns from the `select` list, the code might be syntactically valid.  The procedure doesn't appear to do what the body of the question says it does or should do (if you fix the syntax errors, you're left with code that simply returns whatever value is passed in through some confusingly named variables).  Adding images of errors is frowned on-- please add error messages as text.

Comment: That image is "invoices" etc etc and does not not related to this question?